# Trying to remove the html using jquery with var

Tags: jquery, html

I have a program that removes certain html code from a list of div whenever a person clicks a specific list item.

I can get the ID of the div item selected but how do I pass it in?

```
var divID = //grabbing selected item's divID (no prob here)
$("#xxx").remove(".HtmlClassToBeRemoved");
```

How should I replace xxx which is the div ID?

Comment: `$("#" +divId).removeClass(".HtmlClassToBeRemoved");`

Comment: Adding HTML code will help us to solve your problem

Comment: I think what you need is `$("#" +divId+ ' .HtmlClassToBeRemoved').remove();`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$("#"+divID).remove(".HtmlClassToBeRemoved");
```

Logically thinking that within `$()` there should be a `string` specifying a `selector`, so normal string concatenation would work perfectly.

As pointed out by @bufh, you can also use:

```
$("#" + divID + ".HtmlClassToBeRemoved").remove()
```

Since it will directly select the `HtmlClassToBeRemoved` within the `div` that needs to be removed.

See the fiddle for reference: "http://jsfiddle.net/0f070qmg/"

Comment: Could also be `$("#" + divID + " .HtmlClassToBeRemoved").remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

if divID is a ID without the # its just

```
 $("#"+divID).remove(".HtmlClassToBeRemoved");
```